# How to change SNOW state from "Closed Incomplete" to "Closed Complete"?

Tags: servicenow

For ServiceNow by mistake i update state as **"Closed Incomplete"**, but i want to change to **"Closed Complete"** Can you people help me with this.

I can't able to do anything about this issue. As you know once we set SNOW state can't able to edit. What is the best way to handle the issue.

Comment: If you are an administrator, you have the ability to change the state.

Comment: @Anjo
Can you pls explain in detail how to do that, it is really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Run this script in a background script area.
Assumes "closed complete" is integer 3.
Set the change number you want updated in line 1.

```
var chgNumber = "CHG00200001"
var chgGR = new GlideRecord('change_request');
if (chgGR.get('number', chgNumber)){
    chgGR.state = 3;
    chgGR.update();
}
```

I assume you're running into a security rule or UI Policy that's preventing you from setting the change state in the UI.

If you need to change multiple records, use this snippet

```
var chgNumbers = "CHG00200001,CHG00200002"
var chgGR = new GlideRecord('change_request');
var chgGR.addQuery('number', 'IN', chgNumbers);
var chgGR.query();
gs.info("Changes to be updated: " + chgGR.getRowCount());
while (chgGR.next()){
    chgGR.state = 3;
    chgGR.update();
}
```